# Show connected set is not path connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $A$ be a non-empty connected subset of $\mathbb{R^2}.$  If $A$ is closed, is it necessarily true that $A$ must be path connected?

I believe the answer is no, this only holds when $A$ is an open set.  However I am having difficulty coming up with a proof or counterexample.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the closed version of the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).